# Problema ubicación de invalid-feedback en radio buttons

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-grid-layout

Acudo aquí porque no logro que el `div` con clase `invalid-feedback` se ubique de manera correcta al usar radio buttons dentro de `bootstrap 4`

Estoy manejando el siguiente código

```
<div class="container">

<form>

    <h5>Formulario!</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Conex_BT">Conexión</label>
        <select class="form-control is-invalid">
        <option value="">No aplica.</option>
        </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="Err_Conex_BT">El medio de conexión es un campo obligatorio!</div>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input is-invalid" data-val="true" data-val-required="Definir si posee neutro es obligatorio!" id="Conex_BT_N_True" name="Conex_BT_N" required="required" type="radio" value="True">
        <label for="Conex_BT_N_False" class="form-check-label">
            Con Neutro
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input is-invalid" id="Conex_BT_N_False" name="Conex_BT_N" required="required" type="radio" value="False">
        <label for="Conex_BT_N_False" class="form-check-label">
            Sin Neutro
        </label>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="Err_Conex_BT_N">Definir si posee neutro es obligatorio!</div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

[Dejo el JSFiddle donde puede verse claramente cual es el problema.](https://jsfiddle.net/e1v6grn3/14/)

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente, tanto en los `input` de tipo texto, como en los `select` el `div` de clase `invalid-feedback` se ubica correctamente, debajo del control y alineado a la izquierda.

El asunto es que con los radio button deja un margen a la izquierda, asumo, que se debe a que está dentro de la clase `form-check` en lugar de `form-group`, pero el problema es que si lo ubico en esta segunda, la clase `invalid-feedback` está en `display: none;`

¿Cuál sería el método correcto de ubicar el div para que se muestre donde corresponde?

Desde ya muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: El problema que tienes es que la clase invalid-feedback esta ligada al input es por eso que si lo pones fuera de la clase form-check se oculta.
.form-check-input.is-invalid~.invalid-feedback {display: block;}

Entiendo que puedes utilizar javascript para mostrar esa validación, no?

Comment: @AnonimoPer efectivamente, uso javascript para esa validación, estaba la posibilidad de modificar la propiedad display a la fuerza, pero pensaba que estaba malinterpretando la documentación y armando mal el formulario, muchísimas gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles), esta bien en donde estas poniendo el div `invalid-feedback`

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es "reubicarlo" con estilos:

```
.form-check .invalid-feedback {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

A continuación la opción que te propongo en funcionamiento:

```css
.form-check .invalid-feedback {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

<form>

    <h5>Formulario!</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Conex_BT">Conexión</label>
        <select class="form-control is-invalid">
              <option value="">No aplica.</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" id="Err_Conex_BT">El medio de conexión es un campo obligatorio!</div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input is-invalid" data-val="true" data-val-required="Definir si posee neutro es obligatorio!" id="Conex_BT_N_True" name="Conex_BT_N" required="required" type="radio" value="True">
            <label for="Conex_BT_N_False" class="form-check-label">
                Con Neutro
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input is-invalid" id="Conex_BT_N_False" name="Conex_BT_N" required="required" type="radio" value="False">
            <label for="Conex_BT_N_False" class="form-check-label">
                Sin Neutro
            </label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" id="Err_Conex_BT_N">Definir si posee neutro es obligatorio!</div>
        </div>       
    </div>
    
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! había intentado moverlo por css pero me la estaba re complicando :P